# Malformed Action frames in ns-3 mesh network simulation

Tags: networking, network-programming, wireshark, ns-3, mesh-network

I have built a simulation model of the IEEE 802.11s based mesh network in ns-3 version ns3.28. The network consists of one moving node moving randomly and three static nodes. The pcap file generated from the model when viewed in Wireshark shows malformed Action frames.

I have attached the picture below. The same is the case for beacon frames. Can anyone describe why are these packets malformed?

[image: ns-3 based pcap file in wireshark]

Comment: Apparently the Tag Length (117) is wrong (should be 4). The `RIC_DATA` header type is defined [here in the ns-3 code](https://github.com/nsnam/ns-3-dev-git/blob/95de5850290896f02970b1f0d20ff9af4d4fad19/src/wifi/model/wifi-information-element.h#L91) but I don't see anywhere in the code that it is being added to the packet. Do you manually add that header? Can you update the question with the minimal part of your code that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I am not manually adding the header, I am just running the mesh example "mesh.cc" with the different number of nodes. I got the same results even on running the actual "mesh.cc" example.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to fix it in the code but I think I know whats going on. The header is supposed to be a `IE_MESH_PEERING_MANAGEMENT` (117) with sub-type `PEER_CLOSE` (3) and Tag length `7` (see [here](https://github.com/nsnam/ns-3-dev-git/blob/73c12cc768bd083b28deb7994b7da7fecb2ab2fd/src/mesh/model/dot11s/ie-dot11s-peer-management.cc#L48)). The reason for close is set to [`REASON11S_MESH_CONFIRM_TIMEOUT`](https://github.com/nsnam/ns-3-dev-git/blob/62ab39c9f13e2a4849eee3deff70de60f04be80a/src/mesh/model/dot11s/ie-dot11s-peer-management.h#L41) (57).

Somehow it was serialized in the wrong order. You should open a bug with ns3 for them to fix this.